# в phpmyadmin не отображается поле extra

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Добрый день, поставил себе пхмайАдмин, решил создать базу данных и не могу присвоить колонке auto-increment, нет поля extra которое отвечает за это. Подскажите как включить это поле в пхп май админ или как добавить авто-инкремент. Привожу для примера скриншоты

[image: первый]

[image: второй]

Comment: что мешает выполнить запрос `ALTER TABLE hello CHANGE my_id my_id INT(20)AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` ? А вообще используйте что-то получше: `SQLYog` или `MysqlWorkbench` или `Navicat` они используют ресурсы компа и в разы быстрее, чем пхпадмин, который работает через браузер ......добавить наверное можно так http://i.stack.imgur.com/YxbA4.png ....... и галочку `A_I` видно же на фото, которое вы предоставили

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
MODIFY some_column INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Чтобы использовать GUI, выберите в меню пункт STRUCTURE, там список всех полей.
Поле можно отметить как PRIMARY FIELD, нажав на золотой ключик, он должен стать серебряного цвета.